# Производная от софтмакс для обратного распространения ошибки

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Народ добрый день, в сети море разной информации, по вопросу производной софтмакс и как ее использовать в обратном распространении ошибки. Я понял примерно так, подскажите плз, я прав???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

просто далее встает вопрос про матрицу Якоби, скажите, для расчета сети надо использовать, как я на картинке указал или место ф штрих, ставить матрицу Якоби, заранее спасибо.

Или все еще проще?